# Need help in teradata

Tags: teradata

In one of the tables I've a time column where the data is something like this :
01:21:00.000000
 for all the records.

I want to retrieve the data which looks like below.

01:21:00  in teradata.

Please advise. I'm new to teradata and don't know how to achieve this

Comment: Have you looked at the CAST() function? It seems your data is TIME(6) and you want TIME(0).

Answer (score 1):

I don't know a reasonable way to go to less precision in time (or timetamps) in Teradata.  Assuming your column is time(6), you can't just cast that to time(0). You get a DateTime field overflow error.

I do it by casting it to a character field and then back to time(0):

```
select *
from
<your table>
where
cast(cast <your column> as varchar(8)) as time(0) = '01:21:00'
```

Comment: Ahh. The old double CAST()... :)

Comment: It is indeed goofy, but it's the only way I know of.

Answer (score 0):

If your column is timestamp, then we can use Timestamp(0) is  YYYY-MM-DDbHH:MI:SS and Timestamp(6) is YYYY-MM-DDbHH:MI:SS.ssssss (milliseconds extra).

If your column is just time, then we can use 'CAST'.

select cast( as time(0)) from ;

Comment: Doesn't work, because Standard SQL doesn't allow decreasing precision.